# How to project a list of a specific field from a nested list of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb documents, each contains a `pokemon` array, where each item is an object. This is a sample document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("60a8f82df06d8601849b2a01")
  pokemon: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "num": 1,
      "name": "bulbasaur",
      "img": "img.com",
      "type": ["grass", "poison"],
      "height": 112,
      "weight": 33
    },
    {
     
      "id": 2,
      "num": 2,
      "name": "char",
      "img": "img.com",
      "type": ["grass", "poison"],
      "height": 112,
      "weight": 33
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the names from this list.

This is my code

```
const client = new MongoClient(url);
console.log("connected")
await client.connect();
const db = client.db('cluster0');
const collection = db.collection('testing');

let datas = await collection.find({
    'pokemon.0': {
        name: "bulbasaur"
    }
}).toArray();
console.log(datas)
```

Tried different query operators such as text matching but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a document which its first pokemon's name is "bulbasaur", try:

```
let data = await collection.find({"pokemon.0.name": "bulbasaur"})
```

And if you want to return only the pokemon names, you can use projection:

```
let data = await collection.findOne(
  {"pokemon.0.name": "bulbasaur"},
  {_id: 0, names: {$map: {input: "$pokemon", in: "$$this.name"}}}
)
console.log(data.names)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nqKP27Uv7wK)

Comment: nope ...when i try to print to  console after using the ,toarray() method., I am still getting an empty array

Comment: Please provide a sample document as text

Comment: sure, I have provide a sample document

Comment: As a text, not as an image. So we can copy it into the playground

Comment: i have added the sample as text @nimrod serok

Comment: This is good. And what is your expected output?

Comment: to print out that data to the console or just print out the name bulbasour in the console

Comment: I updated the answer. Please also check the playground link in it

Answer (score 1):

If you want particularly that object only then use this

```
db.collection.find({
  "pokemon.name": "Bulbasaur"
},
{
  "pokemon.$": 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want position to be dynamic and still search for "bulbasaur" you can use:

```
db.collection.find({
  "pokemon": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      name: "bulbasaur"
    }
  }
})
```

You can read more about it here =>
[Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

You can also test it on [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E3uV3icq8x9)

Comment: nope still not working